# struts common error forward

Tags: struts

How can I use common forward for all actions. I mean I don't want to write common forward in all actions.

```
<forward name="invalidlogin" path="/invalidlogin.jsp" />
```

I don't want to write this in all `<Actions>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just describing a global forward. Global forwards are defined in the struts-config.xml file. That way, the forward is defined for all actions so any action can use the forward.

So you would place something like the following in your struts-config.xml file:

```
  <global-forwards>
    <forward name="error" path="jsp/error.jsp"/>
  </global-forwards>
```

Then just forward to "error" in your action class:

```
return mapping.findForward("error");
```

Comment: Working on an old Struts 1 app and this saved me from having to have a session expired forward name on like 30 or so items.